# Using in for input python 3.0

Tags: python, function, input

How i use  "in" to test if an word is included in the input?
For example: You going to code an script thats testing if the user input included affront meanings or an claim. When you have an "bad word" than it automatically will be censored.

Comment: `if 'bad word' in input():`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are expected to show some of your own work on your question. For example, have you done a [web search on "Python in operator"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+in+operator&atb=v124-4__&ia=qa) or something like that? What about the results did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already put the input into a string variable. Let's call this input "user_input":

```
user_input
for word in bad_words_list:
    if re.search("\b"+word+"\b", user_input, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        ban_user()
```

"re" is the Python module for regular expressions. re.search() will evaluate to true only if the expression is found.

We add "flags=re.IGNORECASE" to ensure our search is case-insensitive. That way users can't bypass the filter by changing their case.

The reason we add the "\b" escape characters to the regular expression, to force it to only look at whole words.

For example, if I wanted to ban the word "cars," if I did not add the "\b" characters, then the following would be matched:

"I want to drive a car"
"I want to go to **Car**son street."

But once we add the "\b" characters (creating the string "\bcars\b"), then only "I want to drive a car" would be matched, and "I want to go to Carson street" would *not* be matched.

ban_user() could be any statement really; it's just something executed once the word is found. If you're trying to just censor the word, I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to replace strings in Python :)